# How to move file without checking constants in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

The last versions of android studio became showing the dialog by file moving:

[image]

This s absolutely useless and painful, if you use kotlin constants. I like constants and every time when I move my models I have to check every each constant. How to prevent it?